# Identify Datetime64 columns in a dataframe using python

Tags: python

I need to identify which of the columns in a dataframe (having many columns) are "datetime64[ns]".

I imported the csv file and used df.dtype() syntax to display the datatypes.However, the output shows  dtype as "object" instead of "datetime64" for the columns that have dates. Please help, I am a beginner (I have imported "from datetime import datetime").

Comment: `pd.read_csv` generally doesn't infer date types unless explicitly told to do so (i.e. with the `parse_dates` argument; see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)). "object" is the dtype given to strings, so that is how your date variables are stored unless you convert them. You can either convert them on import (with `parse_dates`), or using the [pd.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) method.

Comment: From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) you could try `parse_dates`. As a side note: `from datetime import datetime` does _nothing_ by itself to parse dates, it just gives you access to the `datetime` class should you wish to try create a `datetime` object.